# Monitor playwright tabs in real time

Tags: playwright, playwright-python

I'm making a code using the playwright library, I would like the script to open several files from a list (pandas). But I want to limit the amount of open files at a time. These files are opened in different tabs in the browser.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
   while len(chrome.browser.contexts[0].pages) > abas:
      time.sleep(.5)
   ##rest of the code
```

It's opening the limit I want. However, closing a tab should open another until reaching the limit once again. That doesn't happen.I've done it in selenium this way (which works very well):

```
    for row in df.itertuples():
        while len(self.chrome.window_handles) > abas:
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I’m not familiar enough with Python to know the best way to filter a list, you could use [the is_closed() Page method](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-is-closed) to determine which ones, and thus how many, are actually still open.